# Modify output of localIdentName / getLocalIdent

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I am developing a widget, which can be embedded on "any" website and using the css-loader to give my CSS-class unique names to avoid conflicts.

In my webpack.config.js I have the following line:

```
localIdentName: 'productname-[folder]-[local]',
```

This outputs classnames like:

- productname-src-widgetbox
- productname-Sidebar-sidebar

Is it possible to remove all "-src" from the classnames and lowercase everything?

I found a solution, where I just copied the whole original getLocalIdent() and prepended a replace() and toLowerCase() methods. But this is not a nice solution, I think:

```
const getLocalIdent = (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {

  if (!options.context) {
    options.context = loaderContext.rootContext;
  }

  const request = path
    .relative(options.context, loaderContext.resourcePath)
    .replace(/\\/g, '/');

  options.content = `${options.hashPrefix + request}+${localName}`;

  localIdentName = localIdentName.replace(/\[local\]/gi, localName);

  const hash = loaderUtils.interpolateName(
    loaderContext,
    localIdentName,
    options
  );

  return hash
    .replace(new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\u00A0-\uFFFF]', 'g'), '-')
    .replace(/^((-?[0-9])|--)/, '_$1')
    .replace("-src", "").toLowerCase();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs for css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname), you should be able to use the `getLocalIdent` to create your own custom class name.

Something like this might do what you're looking for

```
getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
  return localIdentName.replace("-src", "").toLowerCase();
},
```

If you'd like some inspiration, [check out the default implementation of `getLocalIdent`.](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/5e702e7d2e081b7f6d372f0c967fdfca6a40a584/src/utils.js#L37)

Comment: Hi! Thanks! But I tried this already... Unfortunatley all my classes are called productname-[folder]-[local] now.

Comment: They can be used in conjunction with each other. For example, you could specify both `localIdentName` and `getLocalIdent`, where `localIdentName` is what you have above, and then use a `getLocalIdent` function to modify that name. If that doesn't work, try logging out `options` from getLocalIdent to see what options you have, to try to generate your preferred string.